# "Too many files open" issue used by FMDatabase/SQLite3

Tags: xcode, macos, sqlite, fmdb

I am using the FMDatabase wrapper for SQLite3 in my OSX App. I do tons of inserts into the database:

```
FMResultSet *results;
results= [db executeQuery:@"select count(*) from `items` where key = ?",[keyPath lowercaseString],nil];

while([results next])
{
    if([results unsignedLongLongIntForColumnIndex:0]>0){
        updateOperation=TRUE;
    }
}
[results close];

if(updateOperation){

    [db executeUpdate:@"update `items` set OSXsize=?,OSXOsize=?, OSXDate=?, UUID=?,sourceFile=?,tombStone=0,SandBoxBookMark=?,songname=?,albumartist=? where key=?",
     size,originalSize, convertedDate,UUID,sourcePath,bookmark,fileName,albumArtist,[keyPath lowercaseString] , nil];
}
else
{
    [db executeUpdate:@"insert into `items`(key,filepath, OSXsize, OSXOsize, OSXdate,UUID,sourceFile,tombStone,SandBoxBookMark,songname,albumartist) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,0,?,?,?)",
     [keyPath lowercaseString], dapPath, size,originalSize, convertedDate,UUID,sourcePath,bookmark,fileName,albumArtist, nil];
}
```

I open the database once, however, I am seeing 4725+file handles attached as the app progresses in activity monitor:

```
/Users/userA/Library/Containers/com.map-pin.Dapper/Data/Library/Application Support/com.map-pin.Dapper/dapperright.sqlite
15
16
...
4724
4725
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this in a multithread app and do you create and open a `db` instance every time you update/insert a row? Do you have `[db close];` somewhere?

Have you tested [FMDatabaseQueue](https://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabaseQueue.html)?

Comment: Using fmdatabasequeue turned on some logging which revealed a query result set which was not properly closed

Answer (score -1):

For the user that runs your database, run the following command:

```
limit maxfiles 4096 16384
```

Afterwards restart the database. Now it should be able to handle 16k files.

How you persist this for  OS X reboots depends on the version of OS X. You will find it by searching in your favorite search engine